# UILabel Text Not Appearing on Some Devices

Tags: iphone, text, uilabel, invisible

I have a simple UILabel setup and was receiving reports from some users that they could not see the information. I did some testing and found that I can see the text on my iPhone 4, but when I test on my old iPhone 3G, the text of the label does not appear. I can see the label (it has a colored background) but there is no text.

I am assuming most of the users have a 3GS or better, but have not nailed it down to exactly who is / is not seeing the error.

Any ideas why this could be happening ?

myLabel is linked up to a UILabel in interface builder.

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
myLabel.text = @"MY MESSAGE";       
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 40);
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that you are using a standard UILabel and not some subclass found on the internet. Are you using a custom font? Are you seeing the red backround? There are many things that could be going wrong, we need some more information.

Comment: Yes, it is just a normal UILabel. Yes, I see the red background. I do not see the text on the 3G but see it on the iPhone 4.

Comment: There is something else wrong besides those 4 lines of code. Try using the debugger to stop the app once the label has been shown and check the individual attributes on myLabel. Make sure the text is not nil, check the fontsize, framesize. I think something will pop out at you.

Comment: I ended up deleting the XIB and re-hooking everything up and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and tracked it down to a font problem.  Helvetica Neue Medium does not appear on my iDevices running iOS 4.2.1.  Helvetica Neue Regular is visible on them.